# from pm4py.objects.log.util import func as functools -> ImportError

Tags: python, importerror

I am running this code to import a module:

```
from pm4py.objects.log.util import func as functools
```

And get this ImportError:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d14af87451f6> in <module>
      1 import pm4py
----> 2 from pm4py.objects.log.util import func as functools

ImportError: cannot import name 'func' from 'pm4py.objects.log.util'
```

Does someone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what do you expect from this code and what is `func`.

`pm4py.objects.log.util` is a python package (as it has an `__init__.py` file and has some modules). When you import something from a package, it recursively imports submodules/subpackages, defined in `__init__.py` file. According to the [pm4py](https://github.com/pm4py/pm4py-core/blob/release/pm4py/objects/log/util/__init__.py) source code, there is no `func` name in this file.

If you want to see what names are accessible from `pm4py.objects.log.util`, you can do the following:

```py
import pm4py.objects.log.util as utils
print(dir(utils))
```

Which prints all the names you can access:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'artificial', 
'basic_filter', 'dataframe_utils', 'filtering_utils', 
'get_class_representation', 'get_log_encoded', 'get_prefixes', 
'index_attribute', 'insert_classifier', 'interval_lifecycle', 'log', 
'pandas_numpy_variants', 'pkgutil', 'sampling', 'sorting', 
'split_train_test', 'xes']
```

Comment: Thank you! I was following a tutorial done by the creators of the library. It seems like `func` does not exist anymore...